# In expo [UIKitCore] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, info.plist

[UIKitCore] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")
To be honest, I am not sure how UIScene works in expo

I get this error every time I run the app on a simulator for testing, right after the splash screen.
The app runs fine though.

I tried to replicate the swift fix in `app.json` but it did not work

```
"expo": {
    ...
    "ios": {
      ...
      "infoPlist":{
        "UISceneConfigurations":{
          
        }
      }
```